# Application in Python that allows a user to play the game Bulls and Cows against a computer

Tags: python, index-error

Write an application in Python that allows a user to play the game Bulls and Cows against a computer.

The game works as follows: The computer chooses a 4-digit number in secret. The digits must all be different. The user then guesses the number and the computer provides the number of matching digits. If the matching digit is in the right position it is a "bull", if it is on a different position it is a "cow". For example:

Computer chooses: 3691

User guesses: 1649

Computer answers: 1 bull and 2 cows

If the user guesses a number with repeat digits that is partially correct the rule is that a correct digit can only count once and bulls count before cows. So for example

Computer chooses: 3691 User guesses: 4211 Computer answers: 1 bull and 0 cows

Your program should report the number of attempts the user needed to guess the number and it should let a user play as many times as they wish in a single session. Hint: you should store the secret as a string.

To accomplish this you will edit two files: bulls_and_cows.py and main.py

These two modules include outlines of the functions they should contain. You must download and use the linked templates. Do not modify the function headers that are provided! Read the comments carefully and implement the functions as specified. Write the code that is needed to complete the three functions in the bulls_and_cows module and the play_game function in the game module. The play_game function must make use of the functions you write in the bulls_and_cows module. Do not modify the main function in the game module. Your code must work with the main function that is provided as is. Don't forget to include a readme.txt file explaining how your program works.

I really don't know how to complete this task. It's for a college course. Also could someone please recommend some useful resources to learn python for beginners. Getting started in coding and any other useful tips for becoming familiar in this space. Thx much appreciation!

I'm struggling on where to start. It's an assignment which my college professor assigned the students. The course is called: COMPUTING IN CONTEXT: COMPUTING AND THE ARTS. There was no perquisite for taking the course. But I'm genuinely lost and not sure where to begin or what to do.

Comment: Perhaps you need to speak to your teacher then? They're in a better position to help you than people on SO.

Answer (score 1):

**First thing - don't panic!**

You're taking your first steps in learning Python - congratulations!

Learning any new skill takes time - nobody is an expert straight away.

**Your course**

If you're feeling overwhelmed, consider asking your lecturer/tutors for advice. They are there to help you learn.

**Online resources**

Here is a free handbook on coding with Python for beginners:
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/the-python-guide-for-beginners/

It comes from a website called free code camp, which offers great programming resources to learn from - for free!

Here is an example of the bulls and cows game, written in Python:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-cows-and-bulls-game/

Note, this will likely not be built the same way you need. You will probably need to build the program differently for your course. Consider this another learning resource.

Good luck with the rest of your Python journey!

Comment: Thank you os much Irish Dev! You're a life saver, I really appreciate, and thanks for the advice as well as the online resources!!